# why all this together doesnt work? please explain

Tags: sql

the first part before the "=" is working, the second part after the "=" also working and the result need to be 1300. so why all this together doesnt work? please explain

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_name, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS sum
FROM clients c, contracts_rent r, payments p
WHERE c.c_id = r.c_id
AND r.contract_id = p.contract_id
GROUP BY c.c_id
HAVING SUM( p.p_sum ) =SELECT MAX( temp.sum ) 
FROM ( SELECT r.c_id AS Cman, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS sum
       FROM contracts_rent r, payments p
       WHERE r.contract_id = p.contract_id
       GROUP BY r.c_id
     ) AS temp
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? Does the query run but you get the wrong result? If so, what result do you get? What do your tables look like and what data do they contain?

Comment: Which `=`? Being more specific would help us help you better

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX( temp.sum ) FROM ( SELECT r.c_id AS Cman, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS su' at line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_name, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS my_sum
FROM clients c, contracts_rent r, payments p
WHERE c.c_id = r.c_id
AND r.contract_id = p.contract_id
GROUP BY c.c_id, c.c_name
ORDER BY my_sum DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Theoretically your solution works if you add some parantheses:

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_name, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS sum
FROM clients c, contracts_rent r, payments p
WHERE c.c_id = r.c_id
AND r.contract_id = p.contract_id
GROUP BY c.c_id
HAVING SUM( p.p_sum ) = (SELECT MAX( temp.sum ) 
FROM ( SELECT r.c_id AS Cman, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS sum
       FROM contracts_rent r, payments p
       WHERE r.contract_id = p.contract_id
       GROUP BY r.c_id
     ) AS temp
)
```

The difference between the solutions is, that the first one yields just one row, regardless if there are two or more rows having the same sum of `p.p_sum`. The second one would yield all `max(sums)`